# Sample config for Logitech Touchpad T650 Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, logitech

I have a Logitech Touchpad T650 which basically works out of the box, except that it very often right-clicks when I want it to two-finger-scroll.

Based on [this post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tweak-your-touchpad-to-taste-in-linux/) I have tried to configure synaptics through synclient, but I can't seem to solve that one issue.

Here is the output from synclient:

```
synclient -l
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 113
    RightEdge               = 2719
    TopEdge                 = 127
    BottomEdge              = 2237
    FingerLow               = 4
    FingerHigh              = 5
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 162
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 56
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = -73
    HorizScrollDelta        = -73
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0542299
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 39
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 5
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 31
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 18
    VertHysteresis          = 18
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1416
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1938
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

I have been trying to tweak `MaxTapTime` is that right? Any other suggestions please? Does anybody have a working config for this device?

Comment: The link mentions a startup script. Are you using that? Or do changes have no effect at all?

Comment: @jacob I am configuring the device with `synclient` in the terminal. I assume the changes I'm making are having some effect, but from a user perspective they are not solving the problem. It's very hard to say whether there is any improvement or not. All I can say is that I am still frequently getting a 'right-click' result when I am trying to 'two-finger-scroll'. I don't even know if I am changing the right parameter (`MaxTapTime`)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `MaxTapTime` from `180` to `80` really changed the behavior of the touchpad for me. Two finger scrolling is not triggering right click anymore and the single tap is working pretty well.

According to the synaptics configuration page http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html the `MaxTapTime` property matches the maximum time your finger is touching the touchpad to detect the tap. Reducing it allows the system not to detect a two finger click when you're doing a two finger scroll

There is also a `MaxTapMove` property which I think have a role in this behavior but I could not find how to change this value for now as the first one has resolve a big part of the problem.